# PHP/Doctrine2 - Implement an interface twice

Tags: php, oop, unit-testing, doctrine-orm

This might be a silly question. I am trying to create a generic repository interface for Doctrine 2 so I can pass it into my controller through direct injection:

```
//TestController.php

public function __construct(TestRepositoryInterface $p_repository){
    //...
}
```

The method signature for an EntityRepository in Doctrine2 is as follows:

```
class EntityRepository implements ObjectRepository, Selectable{
    //...
}
```

`EntityRepository` is missing a few functions that I would like to have in a repository(Add, Delete, Update). So I created a base repository interface and an abstract repository class to encapsulate those functions:

```
interface RepositoryInterface {
    public function add($entity);
    public function delete($entity);
    public function update($entity);
}
```

The abstract repository class extends from `EntityRepository` so I can still get the functionalities of `EntityRepository`.

```
abstract class AbstractRepository extends EntityRepository{
    public function add($entity){
        //...
    }

    public function add($entity){
        //...
    }

    public function add($entity){
        //...
    }
}
```

To tie everything together, I made `TestRepositoryInterface` extend from `RepositoryInterface`, `ObjectRepository`, and `Selectable`.

```
interface TestRepositoryInterface extends RepositoryInterface, ObjectRepository, Selectable{

}
```

Then I can just pass in an implementation of `TestRepositoryInterface` through direct injection:

```
class TestImplementation extends AbstractRepository implements TestRepositoryInterface{
    //...
}
```

Or if I am unit testing, it would be easy to create a mock object or test stub.

My only concern is in `TestImplementation` class. It extends `AbstractRepository` which already implements `ObjectRepository` and `Selectable` (through `EntityRepository`), and at the same time `TestImplementation` also implements `TestRepositoryInterface` which also extends `ObjectRepository` and `Selectable`. So `TestImplementation` is essentially implementing `ObjectRepository` and `Selectable` twice (or is it?). It compiles just fine, but is this a valid approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly OK for a class to implement multiple interfaces that in turn extend common interfaces.  The methods are the same so there are no conflicts.

The only thing you need to worry about is implementing interfaces with same named methods but alternative arguments.

Say you have an interface whose implementations need to be iterated.  You would probably have it implement`\IteratorAggregate`.

Now lets say your implementation class extends `ArrayCollection` (from doctrine common).  Because `ArrayCollection` also implements `IteratorAggregate` it take care of some of your own interface's definitions for you.

When it comes to mixing interfaces, look for issues with compatibility rather than inheritance.